# VIM and Scala -- indentation problems?

Tags: vim, scala

I downloaded Scala 2.8, installed the vim scripts included and tried to type in some Scala code. When I typed in `val x = 1 + 2` and hit ENTER, the indentation goes to below the v. When I type in `val x = (1 + 2)`, the indentation is below the x!

If VIM is used by *anyone* at all for Scala, this bug should've been seen long ago. Or am I the only one seeing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the `indent/scala.vim` from the current 2.8.0.final release I have the same outcome... But I know, that it worked in a earlier release, because I have one file here where it works. Here it is:

```
" Vim indent file
" Language   : Scala (http://scala-lang.org/)
" Maintainer : Stefan Matthias Aust
" Last Change: 2006 Apr 13

if exists("b:did_indent")
  finish
endif
let b:did_indent = 1

setlocal indentexpr=GetScalaIndent()

setlocal indentkeys=0{,0},0),!^F,<>>,<CR>

setlocal autoindent sw=2 et

if exists("*GetScalaIndent")
  finish
endif

function! CountParens(line)
  let line = substitute(a:line, '"\(.\|\\"\)*"', '', 'g')
  let open = substitute(line, '[^(]', '', 'g')
  let close = substitute(line, '[^)]', '', 'g')
  return strlen(open) - strlen(close)
endfunction

function! GetScalaIndent()
  " Find a non-blank line above the current line.
  let lnum = prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1)

  " Hit the start of the file, use zero indent.
  if lnum == 0
    return 0
  endif

  let ind = indent(lnum)
  let prevline = getline(lnum)

  "Indent html literals
  if prevline !~ '/>\s*$' && prevline =~ '^\s*<[a-zA-Z][^>]*>\s*$'
    return ind + &shiftwidth
  endif

  "### Taken from mail on scala mailing list
  "### -------------------------------------
  " Add a 'shiftwidth' after lines that start a block
  " If if, for or while end with ), this is a one-line block
  " If val, var, def end with =, this is a one-line block
  "if prevline =~ '^\s*\<\(\(else\s\+\)\?if\|for\|while\|va[lr]\|def\)\>.*[)=]\s*$'
      "\ || prevline =~ '^\s*\<else\>\s*$'
      "\ || prevline =~ '{\s*$'
      "let ind = ind + &shiftwidth
      "endif
      " Add a 'shiftwidth' after lines that start a block
      " If if, for or while end with ), this is a one-line block
      " If val, var, def end with =, this is a one-line block
      if prevline =~ '^\s*\<\(\(else\s\+\)\?if\|for\|while\)\>.*[)]\s*$'
                  \ || prevline =~ '^\s*\<\(\(va[lr]\|def\)\>.*[=]\s*$'
                  \ || prevline =~ '^\s*\<else\>\s*$'
                  \ || prevline =~ '{\s*$'
          let ind = ind + &shiftwidth
      endif

  " If parenthesis are unbalanced, indent or dedent
  let c = CountParens(prevline)
  echo c
  if c > 0
    let ind = ind + &shiftwidth
  elseif c < 0
    let ind = ind - &shiftwidth
  endif

  "### Taken from mail on scala mailing list
  "### -------------------------------------
  " Dedent after if, for, while and val, var, def without block
  "let pprevline = getline(prevnonblank(lnum - 1))
  "if pprevline =~ '^\s*\<\(\(else\s\+\)\?if\|for\|while\|va[lr]\|def\)\>.*[)=]\s*$'
      "\ || pprevline =~ '^\s*\<else\>\s*$'
      "let ind = ind - &shiftwidth
      "endif
      " Dedent after if, for, while and val, var, def without block
      "let pprevline = getline(prevnonblank(lnum - 1))
      if pprevline =~ '^\s*\<\(\(else\s\+\)\?if\|for\|while\)\>.*[)]\s*$'
                  \ || pprevline =~ '^\s*\<\(\va[lr]\|def\)\>.*[=]\s*$'
                  \ || pprevline =~ '^\s*\<else\>\s*$'
          let ind = ind - &shiftwidth
      endif

  " Align 'for' clauses nicely
  if prevline =~ '^\s*\<for\> (.*;\s*$'
    let ind = ind - &shiftwidth + 5
  endif

  " Subtract a 'shiftwidth' on '}' or html
  let thisline = getline(v:lnum)
  if thisline =~ '^\s*[})]'
        \ || thisline =~ '^\s*</[a-zA-Z][^>]*>'
    let ind = ind - &shiftwidth
  endif

  return ind
endfunction
```

But I have no clue, where the change was introduced... Tried to find it in the SVN history at https://codereview.scala-lang.org/fisheye/browse/scala-svn/scala-tool-support/trunk/src/vim/indent/scala.vim